# Get rid of mutable local variable in Scala

Tags: scala

I have defined a filter method with the following signature

```
def filterAcc(predicate: Element => Boolean, acc: ElementSet): ElementSet = {
  // filter elements which satisfy the predicate into new Set
  var newAccumulator = if (predicate(this.value) acc.add(this.value) else acc
  newAccumulator = this.leftChild(predicate, newAccumulator)
  this.rightChild(predicate, newAccumulator)
}
```

IDE is complaining the following

```
Avoid Mutable local variables
```

My Use case is the following

1. `add` method returns a new Set after adding the element So I have to receive that into another variable.
2. Similarly, `leftChild.filterAcc` will return new Accumulator as a new Element Set

So, every time I am calling `add` or `filterAcc` I have to receive in a new variable. What is the correct way to write this piece of code.

You can assume that logic is correct. I am just trying to dive myself into Scala oriented code flow so want to know the best practice to write such type of logic without warnings/errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no apparent need to make `newAccumulator` mutable.  Simply define a new immutable `val`:

```
  val newAccumulator = if (predicate(this.value) acc.add(this.value) else acc
  val newerAccumulator = this.leftChild(predicate, newAccumulator)
  this.rightChild(predicate, newerAccumulator)
```

In fact the code *could* be further compressed: but I chose not to do so to allow the current level of readability that you have.

Comment: This is the exact thing I had in mind and I did next. I do not want to lose "code readability" so I consider this as one of the nice solutions. I'd wait for a while to accept this. Thanks

Comment: Sometimes what makes such solution ugly to read is not the structure but simply the naming. I would try replace newAccumulator and newerAccumulator with something more to the abstract semantics. New and Newer talk about your idea of it being an immutable set and of a timing of their existence. What seems more interesting in my opinion is what each contains beyond implementation details. Perhaps something like 'withCurrent' and 'withLeft' or so. You may come up with something better.

Comment: @Det The OP/question *is* about structure and not semantics: the answer is written this way to directly respond to their request. Naturally he will not use that naming convention in his final code.

Comment: @javadba Don't know about what an unknown person will naturally do or not do. Particularly if we consider this not to be a private discussion but a public one, read by possibly thousands. As the aspect of readability was thrown in, I considered it worth to add this remark too.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use below approach to avoid `var`:

```
def filterAcc(predicate: Element => Boolean, acc: ElementSet): ElementSet = {
    this.rightChild(predicate, this.leftChild(predicate, applyPredicate(predicate, acc)))
  }

def applyPredicate(predicate: Element => Boolean, acc: ElementSet) = if (predicate(this.value) acc.add(this.value) else acc
```

Comment: This doesn't work, `acc` isn't in scope in `applyPredicate`

Comment: Ahh, sorry. I just copy pasted `if` clause. It's corrected now.

Comment: And now you don't pass `acc` in the call to `applyPredicate`

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I would't use a named val at all for the call to `leftChild`. @javadba's answer is closer to your original but which is more readable is a matter of opinion:

```
def filterAcc(predicate: Element => Boolean, acc: ElementSet): ElementSet = {
  // filter elements which satisfy the predicate into new Set
  val newAccumulator = if (predicate(this.value) acc.add(this.value) else acc
  this.rightChild(predicate, this.leftChild(predicate, newAccumulator))
}
```